# Getting MATLAB R2019b to use Python3.6

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to use python 3.6 within the MATLAB interpreter.  I have both Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed on my machine.  When using the default python 2.7 MATLAB work fine:

```
>> pyenv('Version', '/usr/bin/python')

ans =

PythonEnvironment with properties:

      Version: "2.7"
   Executable: "/usr/bin/python"
      Library: "libpython2.7.so.1.0"
         Home: "/usr"
       Status: NotLoaded
ExecutionMode: InProcess

>> py.sys.version

ans =

Python str with no properties.

2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

However when following MATLAB's directions to change versions of python by entering the path of the python 3 executable file, python will not load:

```
>> pyenv('Version', '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3.6')

ans =

 PythonEnvironment with properties:

      Version: "3.6"
   Executable: "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3.6"
      Library: ""
         Home: "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr"
       Status: NotLoaded
ExecutionMode: InProcess

>> py.sys.version
Unable to resolve the name py.sys.version.
```

I do notice that the library field in pyenv is not filled in for python 3.  So it appears that MATLAB cannot find a python 3 shared object file.  Why would MATLAB have problems finding the libpython shared object file?

Comment: What OS are you running? How did you install Python?

Comment: Also, did you restart MATLAB after chaning the Python version? "You cannot switch between versions of Python in a single MATLAB session." ([source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/system-and-configuration-requirements.html)).

Comment: @CrisLuengo:  I am running CentOS 7 and I did restart MATLAB several times.  I believe the sys admin installed this with a Yum install.  I believe that I may have a python version without the --enable-shared option.  See https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/21

Comment: I think the question is do you type the 2 `pyenv` commands in the same matlab session, because the matlab documentation says that's not possible.

Comment: @alle_meije:  No I do not type the two commands in the same session.

Comment: Can you start the python3 interpreter separately from the terminal and run `import sys; print(sys.executable)`?

Comment: `ldd /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3.6 | grep py`? Also are you able to run it from a regular terminal? But I think you need to install *PyEnv* in your new *Python*: `/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install pyenv`.

Comment: @CristiFati:  ldd /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3.6 | grep py yields: libpython3.6m.so.rh-python36-1.0 => /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.rh-python36-1.0 (0x00007f0476c1f000)

Comment: @CristiFati:  I am getting an error with pip that it cannot install pyenv.  Looking into why.

Comment: Matlab seems to be confused by multiple pythons (or just python3 in general) sometimes. Could this be a lead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091299

Comment: Have you called MATLAB support? You're paying for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all leave python version installation over to anaconda when it comes to matlab.. and work from within python with your matlab scripts. The next steps to get your python/matlab combo (or visa versa) up and running:

1. `conda install matlab_engine`
2. `import matlab.engine`

If you hit the bumper:

> PackageNotFoundError # *(it doesn't install)*.

3. Open the Anaconda prompt (be sure you are in desired python version environment (e.g. not `base` but `matpy37`):

   a) `cd matlabroot\extern\engines\python` or e.g. `cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2019a.app/extern/engines/python` on MacOS. (# change to your matlab version if needed).

   b.1) and type and run `python setup.py install` or in some cases bullet b2).

   b.2) `python setup.py install --prefix "<anaconda installation directory>"`.

If you don't have for example the proposed conda  `matpy37` test environment you can create it as followed:

***i.*** `conda create -n myenv python=3.6.9`  # where e.g. `myenv` = `matpy37`. When install done then:

***ii.***  type `conda activate matpy37` and run from e.g. Ipython your matlab script by starting it form Jupyter Notebook (Windows: start -> find folder anaconda -> icon ***Jupyter Notebook (matpy37)***. Not sure where they hide it in your linux/ubuntu OS.

... in the worse case scenario there are two options (4 and 5):

4. Don't install the python versions via pip but via anaconda if you want to stay away from breaking package dependencies, fixing callbacks, loggers, diving into subprocess errors and exhausting manual updates and/or down-grades due to package incompatabilities, and more...

   ***Why anaconda***:

   You can save your specific environment and its package version into a yml-file and recreate it on another PC/Laptop/OS system. The .ylm is in most cases less than 1Mb. So it fits on an usb-stick (some of us call it.. a thumb-drive ;-).

... and possible a last resort (never had to use this myself):

5. matlab package [condalab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/65873-condalab-control-and-view-anaconda-python-environments-form-within-matlab). Its used for easy switch within matlab.

Answer (score 2):

For me installing `libpython3.6` solved this problem, i.e. `sudo apt install libpython3.6` on my system. Now the `Library` field in `pyenv` is populated and I am able to run python commands.